# Делаю телеграм бота на библиотеке telebot. Нужно чтобы при вводе комманды /serieswolf выводил нужны текст и кнопку 'смотреть'. Помогите пожалуйста

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telebot

```
@client.message_handler(commands=['/serieswolf'])
```

def send_wolf(message):

```
markup_inline = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup()
item_wolf = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text='Смотреть', callback_data='yes')

markup_inline.add(item_wolf)
client.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Волчонок\nЖанр:фэнтези, боевик, триллер, драма, мелодрама\nСерии: 100 серий(6сезонов)\nОзвучка: VO-production',
    reply_markup=markup_inline)
```

@client.callback_query_handler(func=lambda call: True)
def answer_Wolf(call):
if call.data == 'yes':
web.open('http://lordserial.pro/zarubezhnye/920-volchonok.html')

Answer (score 1):

В принципе, код у тебя правильный, поэтому попробуй переустановить библиотеку **telebot**:

`python -m pip uninstall PyTelegramBotAPI`

`python -m pip install PyTelegramBotAPI`

Вот рабочий способ создать **inline**-кнопки:

```
import telebot
from telebot.types import InlineKeyboardMarkup, InlineKeyboardButton

bot = telebot.TeleBot(TOKEN)

@bot.message_handler(commands=['serieswolf'])
def send_wolf(message):
    markup = telebot.types.InlineKeyboardMarkup()
    markup.add(types.InlineKeyboardButton(text="Смотреть", url="http://lordserial.pro/zarubezhnye/920-volchonok.html"))
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Волчонок\nЖанр:фэнтези, боевик, триллер, драма, мелодрама\nСерии: 100 серий(6сезонов)\nОзвучка: VO-production", reply_markup=markup)
```

Замени переменную `TOKEN` на свою и попробуй запустить код, всё должно работать.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, но способ не работает. Сделал всё как в ответе

Comment: Возможно, у тебя что-то не так с версией библиотеки, поищи в интернете, как установить самую последнюю. Я вот её установил первый раз на комп, используя команду которую оставил в ответе, и у меня всё работает точно по этому коду.

Comment: Бот заработал. Огромное спасибо